# How to overload ofstream operator in c++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload an operator so I can write it into a file I created:

```
typedef struct Square {
    pawn *pawns[2] = { nullptr,nullptr };
}square;

class game {

    player players[2];
    score score1 = 0, score2 = 0;
    square board[10][10];

public:
    //constructor
    friend class ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& out, game curr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            out << "=";
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            out << '\n';
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                out << "| ";
            }
            out << index << '\n';
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                out << "=";
            }
        }
        out << '\n';
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            out << " " << index;
        }
        return(out);
    }
```

I mainly get Error C2676 :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File
Error       C2676   binary '<<': 'ofstream' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to define the freestanding function within the declaration of it being a friend function.

Comment: um it's actually a function I've already written and copied inside, is it possible to write functions inside operator overloading?

Comment: 1) `friend class ofstream& operator<<` What does `class` mean in the operator declaration? Why did you put it there? 2) "_what am I doing wrong?_" `operator<<` needs to be implemented as a function (opposed to a method of a class). I assume that you must've heard that, since you _tried_ to mark the "function" as a friend.

Comment: In the declaration of the `<<` operator, change `game curr` to `const game& curr` and change both occurrences of `ofstream` to `ostream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `class` in the line

```
friend class ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& out, game curr)
```

is not correct.

Remove that.

Also,

1. change `ofstream` to `std::ostream` so you can use any `std::ostream`, not just `std::ofstream`.
2. Change the second argument type to a `const&`.

---

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, game const& curr)
{
   ...
}
```

---

It will be better to move the implementation of the function out of the class definition. It will allow you to implement it in a .cpp file.

For that, I suggest:

```
// Declare the class
class game;

// Declare the funtion
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, game const& curr);

// Make the function a friend of the class.
class game
{
   ...
   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, game const& curr);
};


// Define the function outside the class definition.
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, game const& curr)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: can it be used thourgh other classes? what I mean is that I want class A to use a function which get class Game and ofstream, and use this operator, is it possible? or the operator needs to be loaded on class A...

Comment: @AmitBL, I think you are asking whether you can use `game g; std::cout << g << std:;endl;`. The answer to that is "yes". If you are asking something different, please clarify.

Comment: I've overloaded the above operator in Class Game.
I want to this this Opeator inside a function of Class FileUtils,
is it possible?

Comment: If properly declared and accessible, all functions are usable from other functions.  Operator functions are no different.   The reason you've had problems is that the operator function was not properly declared, so the compiler rejected it.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Remove `class` from the line `friend class ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& out, game curr)`.

2)  Add an `#include <iostream>` somewhere above this declaration.

3)  Remove `using namespace std` (since your code is a class definition, which often properly belongs in a header file if you want to use your class types in multiple source files,  and `using namespace std` is bad practice in a header file)   and replace all instances of `ofstream` with `std::ostream`.

4)   (Optional, but good practice). Change the second argument of `operator<<()` to be a `const` reference.

Your question was a bit misleading, as the code sample refers to types that are not defined anywhere.   In future, provide a MCVE